# Achieve operator overloading without using member functions and friend functions

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible for a non-member and non-friend function to achieve this?

Presume that it is a binary operator, which means we need to pass two arguments from different objects. How can it access the private members?

Comment: It's possible but you can't access private members directly.

Comment: This depends on many unknowns. What operator? What are the publically available methods? Etc

Comment: "*you can't access private members directly*" - actually, you can, but it involves some tricky templates to pull off.

Comment: getter functions for the members will work, as will a print method. ex http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb787ec87fc5fb01

Comment: At the end of the day, you can do just about anything in C++. Whether you SHOULD or not, now that's a completely different question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
class Foo{
private:
    int m_i;
public:
    Foo(int i): m_i{i} {}
    int get() { return m_i; }
};

Foo operator+(Foo& foo1, Foo& foo2){
    return {foo1.get() + foo2.get()}; // you can not access m_i directly as you do in member functions and friend functions
}
```

Generally speaking, you use normal functions for operator overloading operators that don't modify the state left operand and don't need access to private or protected members directly.